# Git Submodule Hell on Add: "fatal: remote <url> already exists

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project with several (10+) submodules. I then created another [bare] repository in the same location as all the other submodules' homes and used `git submodule add` to add it to my project.

Unfortunately, when I checked out master, it added a file from the directory instead of recognizing it as a submodule.

For this example, let's assume that it would be mounted/placed at `components/NewComponent` and its url is `customURL://components/NewComponent.git` *(note: `customURL://` is correctly configured in ~/.gitconfig and is being used by the other 10+ submodules perfectly)*.

I have since done `git rm components/NewComponent ; git commit -m "Removed the offending directory"`

However, when I call:

```
git remote add customURL://components/NewComponent.git components/NewComponent
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: remote customURL://components/NewComponent.git already exists.
```

But it's not in the components directory nor in the `.gitmodules` file.

If I manually put it in the files, it doesn't matter if I do a `deinit`, `init`, `update`, `sync`, or even completely clone the repository and re-`init` and re-`update` it, that one thing is completely ignored. `git submodule status` will not show it in the status (though it shows everything else!) or anything. It completely ignores its existence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Notes:

- Current git version: `git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)`

**UPDATE:**

This is a PEBKAC issue.... I should have written `git submodule add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual page of [`git remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html). Name of the remote should go next to `add`.

Comment: Interesting. I originally created them on OS X El Capitan, which's version of git ("git version 2.3.8 (Apple Git-58)") wants `git submodule add [--name <name>] <url> [<rpath>]`, but the one you pointed me wants `git submodule add <name> <url>` and doesn't list a way to put it at a relative path.

Comment: However, it still ignored this submodule when I manually put it in the `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: Oh. I wrote the wrong term when I wrote the above... It's edited now... I feel stupid.